# How to check whether database mail is working or not?

Tags: sql-server, database, email

How can I conditionally check whether SQL Server Database Mail is working or not?

Using `EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp;` we can check the status but I want to check the status conditionally like using If condition.

Answer (score 0):

This stored procedure outputs table result with one value which refers to status.
[help is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187918.aspx) That's what we know :)

You can use this result in .net code by retrieving this result set and checking value or in T-SQL code by [putting result set in temporary table](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC)  and checking value in it.

Hope this helps.